# How to perform a complex update to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

My problem is the following update, which I'm going to make a routine for phpmyadmin.I’ll put a few screenshots of the tables I’m querying.
[wp_postmeta Sku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03IsL.png)

[wp_postmeta Stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAjd2.png)

Here is also an example of a SELECT query that combines tables with each other.
[SELECT higher stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dXlA.png)
The SELECT query works but I haven't been able to change it to an UPDATE query.
SELECT
´´´

```
BEGIN
SELECT wp_posts.ID ,wp_posts.post_title 
AS Name ,wstock.meta_value 
AS Stock ,wsku.meta_value 
AS SKU FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
AS wstock ON wp_posts.ID = wstock.post_id 
and wstock.meta_key='_stock' 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
AS wsku ON wp_posts.ID = wsku.post_id 
AND wsku.meta_key='_sku' 
WHERE post_type = 'product' 
AND wstock.meta_value != 100 
AND wstock.meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND wstock.meta_value > Saldo
AND wsku.meta_value = SKU;
END
```

´´´
The ID comes from another table which links Sku and Stock.

I have been desperately trying various examples of the work on an UPDATE query,
which would update the online store inventory balance.

```
´´´

 BEGIN
    UPDATE 
            (
            SELECT 
                wp_posts.ID ,
                wp_posts.post_title AS Name ,
                wstock.meta_value AS Stock ,
                wsku.meta_value AS SKU 
            FROM wp_posts 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wstock 
                ON wp_posts.ID = wstock.post_id 
                AND wstock.meta_key='_stock' 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wsku 
                ON wp_posts.ID = wsku.post_id 
            )
        SET wstock.meta_value = Saldo 
      
    
          WHERE     
                (
                post_type = 'product' 
                AND wsku.meta_key='_sku' 
                AND wstock.meta_value != 100 
                AND wstock.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
                AND wstock.meta_value != 0
                AND wsku.meta_value = SKU
                AND wstock.meta_value > Saldo
                );
END

´´´
```

It's what I understand the tests that I have completed that the fault lies in a SELECT selection of UPDATE query. I have tried to change it, but I have not found yet functional form.

Stock = Saldo

Test values:
ID:     Name:          Stock:    Sku:
4104    Dynacore D-2S   4        10070

I have tried to debug it in those values just to run SQL in phpmyadmin window.

Comment: Please add table defintions and sample data as text to the question together with expected outcome.BTW your update statement bears no resemblance to the correct syntax please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html particulalry the multi table syntax.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Sory I haven't manage to build sample data yet but I'm working on it today after I have tested this.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
    (
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE meta_key = '_stock'
    AND meta_value != 100 
    AND meta_value IS NOT NULL 
    AND meta_value != 0 // If amount could be zero have to leave away
    ) 
AS Stock 
    (
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' 
    AND meta_value = SKU
    )
AS Sku
SET meta_value = Saldo
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value = Stock.meta_value
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = Sku.meta_value;
END
```

I'm not sure yet does it break the relation between sku and stock but I hope it will work.

Comment: No this won't work yet... I believe I need some joins there...

Answer (score 0):

Here some kind sample data...

```
CREATE TABLE sql_test_a 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    meta_Key VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    meta_value  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)  
); 


INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('1', '_first', 'Mark');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('2', '_first', 'Mike');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('3', '_first', 'Buster');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('4', '_first', 'Fred');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('5', '_first', 'Stevie');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('6', '_first', 'John');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('1', '_last', 'Snow');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('2', '_last', 'Tyson');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('3', '_last', 'Keaton');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('4', '_last', 'Mercury');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('5', '_last', 'Jobs');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('6', '_last', 'Depp');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('1', '_age', '44');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('2', '_aget', '86');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('3', '_age', '17');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('4', '_age', '33');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('5', '_age', '77');

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('6', '_age', '55');
```

How to update _age could be this case.

Comment: This kind a tabe isn't my idea it is the way how wordoress stores the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    (
    SELECT meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE = meta_key sku = '_sku' 
    LEFT JOIN meta_key stock = '_stock' 
    AND meta_value.stock != 100 
    AND meta_value IS NOT NULL 
    AND meta_value.stock != 0 // If amount could be zero have to leave away
    AND meta_value.sku = SKU
    )
AS Stock
SET meta_value = Saldo
WHERE meta_value.stock > Saldo;
END
```

So there is relation between sku and stock not sure yet does it work...

Comment: My biggest problem is probably I don’t know exactly in what order things should happen in the update. I have found a lot of models in which the thing is done as part but I have not found a decent model for this type of update form.